webpack: suppress second "webpack compile successfully" line with constant timestamp
I am able to suppress webpack logs to below.
Logs for 3 compilations below:
Webpack bundle stats plugin took 10174 ms
2024-06-14 13:42:29: webpack compiled successfully

2024-06-14 13:40:31: webpack compiled successfully
Webpack bundle stats plugin took 9450 ms
2024-06-14 13:43:32: webpack compiled successfully

2024-06-14 13:40:31: webpack compiled successfully
Webpack bundle stats plugin took 9633 ms
2024-06-14 13:44:09: webpack compiled successfully

2024-06-14 13:40:31: webpack compiled successfully

Note '2024-06-14 13:40:31: .." logs comes repeatedly (3) with 3 compilation.
This line has the same timestamp with every re-compile.
This constant old timestamp value creates confusion about the time of compilation.
is there a way to turn off this second "webpack compiled successfully" (with constant timestamp) line ?

Please show the webpack config, I can't reproduce

This was due to multiple configuration existing in webpack config.
So, one 'webpack compiled successfully' is coming for each configuration.
This is valid behavior.
